# Upstream timeouts between goapp systemd nginx

Tags: go, nginx, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-18.04, systemd

On ubuntu 18.04LTS I'm using nginx to reverse proxy my go app.

It works when I run the goapp on command line, but when I've tried to put the goapp under systemd control.  nginx  gives a `"502 Bad Gateway".` I think its something to do with systemd, ports and maybe forking ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The nginx error log shows the following for each connection attempt:

```
 2019/10/26 15:24:52 [error] 11974#11974: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 217.42.177.154, server: _, request: "GET /codcall HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/codcall", host: "167.99.192.223"
```

My systemd app config is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=CodCall web service

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/home/codcall/surf-get/codcall

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When running under systemd I get following for the status

```
codcall.service - CodCall web service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/codcall.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-10-26 15:24:07 UTC; 19min ago
 Main PID: 11847 (codcall)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/codcall.service
           └─11847 /home/codcall/surf-get/codcall

Oct 26 15:37:41 codcall-ubuntu codcall[11847]: net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x832a60, 0x8a2320, 0xc00025e0
Oct 26 15:37:41 codcall-ubuntu codcall[11847]:         /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:2007 +0x44
Oct 26 15:37:41 codcall-ubuntu codcall[11847]: net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0xb16240, 0x8a2320, 0xc00025e0
Oct 26 15:37:41 codcall-ubuntu codcall[11847]:         /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:2387 +0x1bd
Oct 26 15:37:41 codcall-ubuntu codcall[11847]: net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc0000ac000, 0x8a2320, 0xc0
Oct 26 15:37:41 codcall-ubuntu codcall[11847]:         /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:2802 +0xa4
Oct 26 15:37:41 codcall-ubuntu codcall[11847]: net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc0000783c0, 0x8a2c60, 0xc000014040)
Oct 26 15:37:41 codcall-ubuntu codcall[11847]:         /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:1890 +0x875
Oct 26 15:37:41 codcall-ubuntu codcall[11847]: created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
Oct 26 15:37:41 codcall-ubuntu codcall[11847]:         /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/net/http/server.go:2927 +0x38e
```

My go app is using the following to listen and serve:

```
func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8001", nil)

}
```

And my nginx config is as follows : I left the / in to check that nginx was running and still serves / as "Welcome to nginx"

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

 location /codcall {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
   }


        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: the truncated log messages in your service status look like a stack trace.

Comment: oh yes - does that mean the goapp is dying under systemd  ? I'll maybe try getting systemd not to restart if it dies . Thanks for spotting.

Comment: restart isn't wrong, but if your service always dies that's going to stop it from handling requests.  Systemd service restarts should be rare.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225401/how-to-see-full-log-from-systemctl-status-service can help you see the full logs.

Comment: Yes your correct- I meant to see if the app stayed dead. I've now found the app is panicking under systemd but OK when manually run on the command line. I can see the following in log 2019/10/26 16:17:38 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:50538: runtime error: invalid memory.  Thanks for the lead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the go program running under systemd could not find my template file. Once I put in the full path for the template file in the go app it worked.

So

```
t, _ := template.ParseFiles("template.gohtml")
```

had to become

```
t, _ := template.ParseFiles("/home/myapp/mytemplates/template.gohtml")
```

I also should have checked for my template var t not being nil.